# How can I persist go 1.11 modules in a Docker container?

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, vgo, go-modules

I am migrating a Go 1.10 app to Go 1.11. This also includes migrating from [`dep`](https://golang.github.io/dep/) to [`mod`](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules) for managing dependencies.

As the application depends on a database, I am using a `docker-compose` to set up the local development environment. With Go 1.10 I simply mounted the local repository (including the `vendor` folder) into the correct location in the container's `GOPATH`:

```
web:
  image: golang:1.10
  working_dir: /go/src/github.com/me/my-project
  volumes:
    - .:/go/src/github.com/me/my-project
  environment:
    - GOPATH=/go
    - PORT=9999
  command: go run cmd/my-project/main.go
```

Since Go 1.11 ditches `GOPATH` (when using modules that is) I thought I could just do the following:

```
web:
  image: golang:1.11rc2
  working_dir: /app
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  environment:
    - PORT=9999
  command: go run cmd/my-project/main.go
```

This works, but every time I `docker-compose up` (or any other command that calls through to the Go tool) it will resolve and re-download the dependency tree from scratch. This does not happen (rather only once) when I run the command outside of the container (i.e. on my local OS).

How can I improve the setup so that the Docker container persists the modules being downloaded by the `go` tool?

Comment: you can always perform the go build up on host then just supply the binary to your container ... in my case the compile happens inside a different container

Comment: Note that you are using go1.11rc2, which is a release candidate, not the final go1.11 release.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not mentioned in the wiki article on modules, but from reading the updated docs on the [go tool](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-GOPATH_and_Modules), I found out that when using Go modules, the `go` tool will still use `GOPATH` to store the available sources, namely `$GOPATH/pkg/mod`.

This means that for my local dev setup, I can 1. define the `GOPATH` in the container and 2. mount the local `$GOPATH/pkg/mod` into the container's GOPATH.

```
web:
  image: golang:1.11rc2
  working_dir: /app
  volumes:
    - .:/app
    - $GOPATH/pkg/mod:/go/pkg/mod
  environment:
    - GOPATH=/go
    - PORT=9999
  command: go run cmd/my-project/main.go
```

Comment: You also can create a new volume to keep an isolate gopath inside the docker container

Comment: @Motakjuq How would that look like in the docker-compose file?

Answer (score 7):

You can use a volume instead of your local `GOPATH`. the docker-compose.yml is like:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    image: golang:1.11
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
        - .:/app
        - cache:/go
    environment:
        - PORT=9999
    command: go run cmd/my-project/main.go

volumes:
  cache:
```

The volume `cache` is going to persist all the changes on the GOPATH for the container.